# Laravel9 with Postgis whereRaw() question mark is not supposed to be parameter

Tags: postgresql, laravel-9, raw

I need to use whereRaw query which looks like this

```
return $query->whereHas('translations', function(Builder $q) use ($value) {
    $q->whereRaw("unaccent(title) ILIKE unaccent('%?%')", [$value]);
});
```

This builder throws me this error:
**bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000003" requires 0**

So I dont know what should I do. The expresion in unaccent() function has to be enclosed by single quotes otherwise it does not work at all. But then the question mark is not supposed to be a query parameter.

Does somebody know how to solve this issue?

**EDIT:**
I found out that this work but I really dont like it.

```
return $query->whereHas('translations', function(Builder $q) use ($value) {
    $q->whereRaw("unaccent(title) ILIKE unaccent('%'||?||'%')", [$value]);
});
```

Comment: Use concat(): $q->whereRaw("unaccent(title) ILIKE unaccent(concat('%', ?, '%'))", [$value]);